# Agent job will not run

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-agent, jobs

I created a JOB to run a simple package that runs a query and saves the results to an Excel file. If I try to run the job In SQL Management Studio I get an error saying:

> SQLServerAgent is not currently running so it cannot be notified of
>   this action. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 22022).

I made sure that SQLServerAgent was in fact running and tried running the job again (from SQL Managment Studio) but still got the same message.

I found this [knowledge base article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/911841) which is telling me that I have to edit the Registry in order to resolve the problem.

Before I go in and start messing with the registry which is something I really don't want to do I was wondering if anyone else has experienced this problem and if they had to edit their registry to fix it?

Comment: Have you tried restarting the SQL Agent?

Comment: i haven't. I will give that a try and report back tommorow. Thanks.

Comment: Look in the SQL Server Agent's error log for any peculiar and indicative messages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out I was connecting to a Load Balancer which redirects me to either one of 2 sql servers which are synchronized ( for better performance) the SQLServer Agent was turned on on one of the servers but it was off on the other server. I needed to create my job on the main server (which has the agent service running). I didn't know we had 2 SQL servers that were identical and that I was connecting to a different one every other time. Sorry about that, but thanks again for the helpful comments, I found some interesting things in the error logs that helped me figure this all out. Thanks again!